# Grails 2.1.0 unable to install webflow plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm running Grails 2.1.0 and I can't install the webflow plugin:

```
$ grails install-plugin webflow
| Plugin installed.

$ grails
| Configuring classpath

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
module not found: org.springframework.webflow#org.springframework.webflow;2.0.8.RELEASE
...
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: org.springframework.webflow#org.springframework.webflow;2.0.8.RELEASE: not found
:: org.springframework.webflow#org.springframework.binding;2.0.8.RELEASE: not found
:: org.springframework.webflow#org.springframework.js;2.0.8.RELEASE: not found
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install-plugin is deprecated in grails 2.0. Edit plugins section from BuildConfig.groovy file:

```
plugins{
    ...
    compile ":webflow:2.0.0"
}
```

And happy webflow coding. By the way, if you want understand more deeply grails webflow I recomend you to read http://livesnippets.cloudfoundry.com/docs/

Comment: Thanks, that saved me a lot of pain, i appreciate the link also :)