# removing plugin in Grails

Tags: grails

I had `grails 1.3.7`, and I upgrade to `grails 2.1.0`, but when I ran `grails run-app` I got the following error:

```
      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/yui/[revision]/yui-[revision].zip
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: org.grails.plugins#yui;[2.6.0,): not found
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
```

I tried to `grails install-plugin yui` and `grails uninstall-plugin yui`, but neither of them worked. I don't really need the `yui` plugin, but any solution will be acceptable. How can i solve that problem?

Comment: have you tried calling grails refresh-dependencies after doing a grails clean? If all else fails, kill your .grails directory and things should work.

Comment: @tomas Yes. both yielded both outcome as in the question ... unresolved dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have a line like `compile ":yui:2.x.x.x"` in your `BuildConfig.groovy` or `plugins.yui 2.x.x.x` in `application.properties`

[The word on the street](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Webflow-won-t-stay-installed-td4626244.html) says that `grails install-plugin` is now deprecated after Grails 2.x and modifying `BuildConfig.groovy` [is the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902753/grails-2-1-0-unable-to-install-webflow-plugin) to install plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You need show dependencies with 'grails dependency-report' Then you can view a HTML report with any plugin using the 'yui' plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem...I just copied another version which I found on
my disk into the lib folder of my application, like the following:

cp /tmp/yui_2.7.0.zip lib

cd lib/

cp yui_2.7.0.zip yui-2.6.0.zip

Than I start the grails compile and everything seems to be ok
when I run the triple:

grails upgrade 
grails compile

and it seems to have no complaint any more...

therbert@mail:~/grapp/dhc$ grails compile | Resolving plugin JAR

dependencies :: problems summary :: :::: ERRORS

```
     Server access Error: Connection refused url=http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-releases-local/org/grails/plugins/yui/%5B2.6.0,)/yui-%5B2.6.0,).pom
```

> ```
>     Server access Error: Connection refused url=http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-releases-local/org/grails/plugins/yui/maven-metadata.xml
>
>     Server access Error: Connection refused url=http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-releases-local/org/grails/plugins/yui/%5B2.6.0,)/yui-%5B2.6.0,).zip
> ```
>
> | Compiling 290 source files Note: Some input files use or override a> deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note:
>
> Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. | Compiling 28 source
>
> files. therbert@mail:~/grapp/dhc$ grails upgrade | Environment set to
>
> development.....
>
> >
>
> ```
>     WARNING: This target will upgrade an older Grails application to 2.1.0.
>
>     Are you sure you want to continue?
>
>                [y,n] y | Plugin 'hibernate' with version '2.1.0' is already
> ```
>
> installed | Plugin 'tomcat' with version '2.1.0' is already
>
> installed | Project upgraded therbert@mail:~/grapp/dhc$ grails compile
>
> | Compiling 290 source files Note: Some input files use or override a
>
> deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note:
>
> Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. | Compiling 28 source
>
> files.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering if there was ever any answer to this question

From looking at the grails dependency-report, its the grails-ui plugin that imports in the bubbling plugin which then imports the yui plugin.

I tried excluding the bubbling and yui plugins in BuildConfig.groovy but unfortunately that did not work. 
@mootinator - I checked both BuildConfig.groovy and my application properties and none of these files have a reference to yui